# Why Kendo DropDownlist can not call action method when initialized

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo DropDownlist as follow

```
<%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("AssignDisciplineId")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
             {
                dataSource.Read(read =>
                {  
                    read.Action("DisciplinesBySportAjax","Shared").Data("onDisciplinesBySportData");                        
                });
              })
        .Events(events => events    
                 .Change("onAssignDisciplineComboChanged")
               )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;" })
%>

function onDisciplinesBySportData(e)
{
    var sportId = $('#AssignSportsId').data('kendoDropDownList').value();
    return { sportId: sportId }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisciplinesBySportAjax(string sportId)
{
     var sports = this._sportBL.GetDisciplinesBySport(sportId);

     return new JsonResult
     {
         Data = new SelectList(sports, "Id", "Description")
     };
}
```

But strangely enough, it does not execute DisciplinesBySportAjax in datasource.read and no data appears in the DropDownList. When changing to BindTo replacing DataSource, it works fine but I do not know how to dynamically reload its content in Jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because a DropDownList doesn't use POST to get the data. Either remove `[HttpPost]` or specify you want to use POST in the DataSource's Transport config.

I haven't checked if your method is done properly but that is the reason it's not being called at all.

Comment: Thanks, DisciplinesBySportAjax is executed after removing [HttpPost]. But dropdownlist is empty. What is the problem? Is returned jsonResult correct?

Comment: Well your code is general seems a bit odd to me. First or all, why do you create the JsonResult? Use the Json() method. It handles stuff for you so you dont have to worry about them. Second is that if you dont use Post request, you have to allow Get in yout Json behavior. With the JSON method there should be an overload or in your JsonResult. Also consider not returning a SelectList. You sent a bunch of junk when you use that. And finally, you can set DataValueField and DataTextField on your dropdownlist to make sure it uses the right fields.

Comment: This code is old that is from Telerik MVC2. I have changed to Json() but it is still not working. Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448824/why-kendo-dropdownlist-can-not-be-initialized-by-json-result-from-controller-act?noredirect=1#comment45236254_28448824. Welcome any of your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Action as below:

> ```
>  [HttpPost]
>  public ActionResult DisciplinesBySportAjax([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string sportId) 
>  {
>      var sports = this._sportBL.GetDisciplinesBySport(sportId);
>
>      return new JsonResult
>      {
>          Data = new SelectList(sports, "Id", "Description")
>      }; 
>  }
> ```

Alternatively if you are looking for cascading the drop-downs then you can use the BindTo on the child drop-down and use JS to filter the values depending on the parent drop-down value.