# Why Kendo DropDownList can not be initialized by json result from controller action

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo DropDownlist as follow

```
<%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("AssignDisciplineId")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
             {
                dataSource.Read(read =>
                {  
                    read.Action("DisciplinesBySportAjax","Shared").Data("onDisciplinesBySportData");                        
                });
             })
        .Events(events => events    
                 .Change("onAssignDisciplineComboChanged")
               )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;" })
%>

function onDisciplinesBySportData(e)
{
    var sportId = $('#AssignSportsId').data('kendoDropDownList').value();
    return { sportId: sportId }
}

public JsonResult DisciplinesBySportAjax(string sportId)
{
     var sports = this._sportBL.GetDisciplinesBySport(sportId);

     return Json(new SelectList(sports, "Id", "Description"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

But dropdownlist is filled with [object object]. After adding following to Html.Kendo().DropDownList()

```
.DataTextField("Description")
.DataValueField("Id")
```

dropdownlist is filled with [undefined]. I need help on this. Thanks.

Comment: What's in your `sports` variable in the last method?

Comment: sports is List<string, string> whose names are "Id" and "Description".

Comment: Do you have a model for Sports? Maybe this could work: `return Json(sports.Select(s => new SportsModel { Description = s.Description, Id = s.id }).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: List<string, string> doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pluc, maybe he meant `List<string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: @chiapa I know he meant one of those. I'm merely pointing out the fact that he made a mistake so he can correct himself. Computer science is a very precise science and I don't want to take guesses on someone's mistake.

Comment: @user585440 As I told you in your last post, you shouldn't return a select list from your controller action. You should return a list of objects or even a list of anonymous objects. To understand what is going on, you should consider using something like Fiddler (although I hate it since it was bought by Telerik) or a better alternative. You will be able to see the Json returned by the server. But if you don't want to understand, I would suggestion returning `sports.Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Description })` and keep you .DataTextField / DataValueField config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing DisciplinesBySportAjax() to

```
public JsonResult DisciplinesBySportAjax(string sportId)
{
    var sports = this._sportBL.GetDisciplinesBySport(sportId);

    return Json(sports, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It works fine, despite it still needs DataTextField("Description") and DataValueField("Id").